# Do not step into function call in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm debugging a binary without debugging information on linux with gdb. I want to break just before the first call to `puts` but not enter the function.

I have tried the following:

```
gdb> b puts
gdb> r
```

or

```
gdb> b main
gdb> b puts
gdb> r
gdb> c
```

But gdb always enters `puts` instead of breaking before the syscall.

Answer (score 0):

> But gdb always enters puts instead of breaking before the syscall.

That's what you *asked* GDB to do.

If you want to stop before the `CALL puts` instruction, you need to `disas main`, find the `CALL puts` instruction, and set a breakpoint on that instruction:

```
(gdb) start  # stop in main to get the binary relocated
(gdb) disas
...
   0x0000555555555147 <+14>:    callq  0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
...
(gdb) break *0x0000555555555147
(gdb) cont

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000555555555147 in main ()
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x555555555147 <main+14>:    callq  0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
```

P.S. `syscall` means something else entirely.